# C++ Ruby Extension with External Libraries

Tags: c++, ruby, linker

I started a little experiment today: I wrote a C++ class which depends on some other libraries (ALGLIB, Eigen, internal tools) and I wanted to create a Ruby wrapper for that class. I'm currently using [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org/) to do that. First I wrote a very simple C++ wrapper for my class:

```
// @file MLPWrapper.h
#pragma once

#include "mlp/MLP.h"
#include <ruby.h>

class MLPWrapper
{
  MLP mlp; // <- my C++ class
public:
  ...
  void fit()
  {
    ...
    mlp.fit(stop);
  }
};
```

The library's cpp-file is this:

```
// @file cmlp.cpp
#include "rice/Data_Type.hpp"
#include "rice/Constructor.hpp"
#include "MLPWrapper.h"

using namespace Rice;

extern "C"
void Init_cmlp()
{
  Data_Type<MLPWrapper> rb_cMLPWrapper = define_class<MLPWrapper>("MLP")
      .define_constructor(Constructor<MLPWrapper>())
      ...
      .define_method("fit", &MLPWrapper::fit);
}
```

And this is the extconf.rb:

```
require "mkmf-rice"

$CFLAGS << "-O3"

HEADER_DIRS = [
  "..",
  "../../external/libraries/eigen-eigen-3.0.1",
  "../../external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src",
  "../../external/libraries/CMA-ESpp"
]
LIB_DIRS = [
  "../../build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src",
  "../../build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es",
  "../../build/src/tools"
]

dir_config("libs", HEADER_DIRS, LIB_DIRS)

have_library("libtools")
have_library("libalglib")

create_makefile("cmlp")
```

Everything works fine except linking. Obviously the header files of the libraries are included, otherwise it would not compile. But when I run a little test program ("require "cmlp"; mlp = MLP.new") in Ruby it does not find the symbol _ZN6LoggerC1ENS_6TargetESs, which is part of libtools (an enum). This is what happens when I build the C++ extension and execute the test program:

```
$ ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lrice... yes
checking for main() in -llibtools... no
checking for main() in -llibalglib... no
checking for main() in -llibcmaes... no
creating Makefile
$ make
g++ -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -I.. -I../../external/libraries/eigen-eigen-3.0.1 -I../../external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src -I../../external/libraries/CMA-ESpp     -I/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/include -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC -O3   -Wall -g -c cmlp.cpp
g++ -shared -o cmlp.so cmlp.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L../../build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src -L../../build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es -L../../build/src/tools -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/lib    -lrice -lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
$ ruby test.rb
ruby: symbol lookup error: ./cmlp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6LoggerC1ENS_6TargetESs
```

The libraries are all compiled with CMake (add_library(...)) and are located at

```
../../build/src/tools/libtools.so
../../build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src/libalglib.so
../../build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es/libcmaes.so
```

I don't know how to solve this problem on my own and I could not find any helpful documentation for my problem. How do i fix this extconf.rb? I appreciate every hint.

edit: OK, I changed the extconf.rb:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mkmf-rice"

BASE_DIR = "/bla/"

$CFLAGS << " -O3"

dir_config("tools", [BASE_DIR + "src", BASE_DIR + "external/libraries/eigen-eigen-3.0.1"], BASE_DIR + "build/src/tools")
unless have_library("tools")
  abort "tools are missing. please compile tools"
end

dir_config("alglib", BASE_DIR + "external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src", BASE_DIR + "build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src")
unless have_library("alglib")
  abort "alglib is missing. please compile alglib"
end

dir_config("cmaes", BASE_DIR + "external/libraries/CMA-ESpp", BASE_DIR + "build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es")
unless have_library("cmaes")
  abort "cmaes is missing. please compile cmaes"
end

create_makefile("cmlp")
```

The generated Makefile is:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

#### Start of system configuration section. ####

srcdir = .
topdir = /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
hdrdir = $(topdir)
VPATH = $(srcdir):$(topdir):$(hdrdir)
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
prefix = $(DESTDIR)/usr
sharedstatedir = $(prefix)/com
mandir = $(prefix)/share/man
psdir = $(docdir)
oldincludedir = $(DESTDIR)/usr/include
localedir = $(datarootdir)/locale
bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
libexecdir = $(prefix)/lib/ruby1.8
sitedir = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/site_ruby
htmldir = $(docdir)
vendorarchdir = $(vendorlibdir)/$(sitearch)
includedir = $(prefix)/include
infodir = $(prefix)/share/info
vendorlibdir = $(vendordir)/$(ruby_version)
sysconfdir = $(DESTDIR)/etc
libdir = $(exec_prefix)/lib
sbindir = $(exec_prefix)/sbin
rubylibdir = $(libdir)/ruby/$(ruby_version)
docdir = $(datarootdir)/doc/$(PACKAGE)
dvidir = $(docdir)
vendordir = $(libdir)/ruby/vendor_ruby
datarootdir = $(prefix)/share
pdfdir = $(docdir)
archdir = $(rubylibdir)/$(arch)
sitearchdir = $(sitelibdir)/$(sitearch)
datadir = $(datarootdir)
localstatedir = $(DESTDIR)/var
sitelibdir = $(sitedir)/$(ruby_version)

CC = gcc
LIBRUBY = $(LIBRUBY_SO)
LIBRUBY_A = lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static.a
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -l$(RUBY_SO_NAME)
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -lruby1.8-static

RUBY_EXTCONF_H = 
CFLAGS   =  -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC $(cflags) -O3 
INCFLAGS = -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.
DEFS     = 
CPPFLAGS =  -I/bla/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp -I/bla//external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src -I//bla/src -I/bla/external/libraries/eigen-eigen-3.0.1     -I/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/include
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)  -Wall -g
ldflags  = -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/lib
dldflags = 
archflag = 
DLDFLAGS = $(ldflags) $(dldflags) $(archflag)
LDSHARED = g++ -shared
AR = ar
EXEEXT = 

RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby1.8
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby1.8
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearch = x86_64-linux
ruby_version = 1.8
ruby = /usr/bin/ruby1.8
RUBY = $(ruby)
RM = rm -f
MAKEDIRS = mkdir -p
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROG = $(INSTALL) -m 0755
INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 644
COPY = cp

#### End of system configuration section. ####

preload = 

CXX = g++
libpath = . $(libdir) /bla/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es /bla/build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src /bla/build/src/tools
LIBPATH =  -L. -L$(libdir) -L/bla/build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es -L/bla/build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src -L/bla/build/src/tools
DEFFILE = 

CLEANFILES = mkmf.log
DISTCLEANFILES = 

extout = 
extout_prefix = 
target_prefix = 
LOCAL_LIBS = 
LIBS = -lcmaes -lalglib -ltools -lrice -lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
SRCS = cmlp.cpp
OBJS = cmlp.o
TARGET = cmlp
DLLIB = $(TARGET).so
EXTSTATIC = 
STATIC_LIB = 

BINDIR        = $(bindir)
RUBYCOMMONDIR = $(sitedir)$(target_prefix)
RUBYLIBDIR    = $(sitelibdir)$(target_prefix)
RUBYARCHDIR   = $(sitearchdir)$(target_prefix)

TARGET_SO     = $(DLLIB)
CLEANLIBS     = $(TARGET).so $(TARGET).il? $(TARGET).tds $(TARGET).map
CLEANOBJS     = *.o *.a *.s[ol] *.pdb *.exp *.bak

all:        $(DLLIB)
static:     $(STATIC_LIB)

clean:
        @-$(RM) $(CLEANLIBS) $(CLEANOBJS) $(CLEANFILES)

distclean:  clean
        @-$(RM) Makefile $(RUBY_EXTCONF_H) conftest.* mkmf.log
        @-$(RM) core ruby$(EXEEXT) *~ $(DISTCLEANFILES)

realclean:  distclean
install: install-so install-rb

install-so: $(RUBYARCHDIR)
install-so: $(RUBYARCHDIR)/$(DLLIB)
$(RUBYARCHDIR)/$(DLLIB): $(DLLIB)
    $(INSTALL_PROG) $(DLLIB) $(RUBYARCHDIR)
install-rb: pre-install-rb install-rb-default
install-rb-default: pre-install-rb-default
pre-install-rb: Makefile
pre-install-rb-default: Makefile
$(RUBYARCHDIR):
    $(MAKEDIRS) $@

site-install: site-install-so site-install-rb
site-install-so: install-so
site-install-rb: install-rb

.SUFFIXES: .c .m .cc .cxx .cpp .C .o

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(INCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) $(INCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(INCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

.C.o:
    $(CXX) $(INCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(DLLIB): $(OBJS) Makefile
    @-$(RM) $@
    $(LDSHARED) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBPATH) $(DLDFLAGS) $(LOCAL_LIBS) $(LIBS)



$(OBJS): ruby.h defines.h
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
../../build/src/tools/libtools.so
../../build/external/libraries/alglib/cpp/src/libalglib.so    
../../build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es/libcmaes.so
```

could be the problem. I would try absolute paths here, I could imagine that the pwd is a different one than you expected while running `ruby extconf.rb`. 
Also, I assume you need a `dir_config` entry for each library you'd like to link in. So

```
dir_config('libs', HEADER_DIRS, LIB_DIRS)
```

should be replaced by

```
dir_config('tools', '<Path to include dir>', '<Path to lib dir>')
dir_config('alglib', '<Path to include dir>', '<Path to lib dir>')
```

Note that the leading 'lib' should be omitted, just like you would in the -l linker option.
Next, if you want to be absolutely sure that a library is found, replace

```
have_library('libtools')
```

by

```
have_library('tools') or raise
```

Again, 'lib' is omitted.

If you still can't solve the problem, please post the Makefile generated by `ruby extconf.rb'.

Comment: OK, your suggestions helped me a bit. Ruby finds the libraries now but they are not loaded when I execute the test script. This is the result:
_./cmlp.so: libcmaes.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - ./cmlp.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from test.rb:2_
I attached the Makefile.

Comment: When I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH it works, when a try to link with static libraries, the following error occures: _/usr/bin/ld: /bla/build/external/libraries/CMA-ESpp/cma-es/libcmaes.a(timings.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `clock@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC_ Is there any better way to solve this problem than setting the environment variable?

Comment: Yes, if you set the 'rpath' option of your linker correctly ([see also](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)), there is no need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Without rice, I can confirm this is set correctly in your Makefile when you call `ruby extconf.rb --with-tools-lib-dir=<PATH> --with-alglib-dir=<PATH>'. Maybe you give that a try? Check in the generated Makefile if the runtime search path is set correctly. Another option is of course to simply install your libraries in one of the standard search paths.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I did as a quick fix now is: $LDFLAGS << " -Wl,-rpath,#{tools_path/alglib_path}"